# Problem with N-repeating a set of commands | Katalon Chrome extension

Tags: loops, selenium, testing, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

This works perfectly for a long time in the old Selenium IDE Firefox add-on but it doesn't work properly in the Katalon Chrome extension.

Basically, I'm opening a particular link, I'm writing a text in a specific field and I click on a button to submit the entered value. The first command  **store | 5 | Y** should result in the procedure written in the previous sentence to be executed 5 times (not simultaneously). For some reason, in the Katalon extension I only get 2 full repeats and one partial one (text entered without submitting it), after which the execution is stopped and the log says "Test case passed".

Screenshot
[image]

Thank you in advance for any solution.